# Creating custom command icon on TeXStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

So, I use TeXStudio on Mac with MacTex and have a couple of custom commands. I can access them via Tools->User->xxx menu and of course with a keyboard shortcut. But, is there anyway to create a clickable icon in the toolbar for a custom command?

[image: TeX Studio Toolbar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that as per [chapter 1.8 in the Texstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION07).

Menu > Options > Configure TeXstudio > Toolbars >  [checked] Show advanced options > pick the Toolbar you want to add the icon to from the left dropdown > pick 'All menus' from the right dropdown > navigate & select your 1st custom command in the right panel > click the left arrow to add that action to the toolbar > right click the newly added action in the left panel > Load other icon > select an icon (perhaps custom made and saved as SVG) > click Ok.

Test and redo with 2nd custom command.

Comment: How can I create a button near the buttons for Bold, Italics...  which inserts the quotation symbol  ``'' ?